# Error when trying to save an entity because ID is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating an app using Java Spring. I have two entities - User and Machine.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    // etc.
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    @NotNull
    private User createdBy;
}
```

When I'm saving a new User, I'm **not** passing the id, and it gets saved successfully.
When I'm saving a new Machine and I don't pass the id, I get an error that validation failed. When I pass the id or remove the @NotNull, it gets saved successfully. Why is that? It's defined the same way, and both entities get saved the same way.

The error I'm getting: `ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=id, rootBeanClass=class raf.edu.rs.nwpbackend.model.Machine, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}`

Comment: is the user set for the machine?

Comment: Yes. The issue just seems to be Machine's id field, because when I pass the id or when I remove the @NotNull from that id, it gets saved...

Comment: Could you show me both imports of the NotNull? Maybe they're different? Just a thought.

Comment: @ElioRahi It's same for both - "import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull".

Comment: Well, in theory, both should throw a validation error, as `@NotNull` should be validated before the call to the database and `GenerationType.IDENTITY` requires a call to database to create the id in the first place. Thus the ID would still be null when the validation happens. Also `@NotNull` is not necessary with `@Id` and can safely be removed

Comment: @NikolaGrujic `NotBlank`? We are talking about `@NotNull` here

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Sorry, wrong copy-paste. Edited the comment. Thanks, I'll remove `NotNull` annotation for ids.

Answer (score 1):

You may remove @NotNull from both ids. This annotation is a bean validation, made before database insert.

See the exception message: javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull` means that data member is compulsory and need to set in that object
Because you are using `@Genratedvalue()` this means it saves the id  in the increment order in the database
`@Id` means primary key it has the condition not null  explicitly you don't need to mention it
if you mention it then you have set id the object which you are passing
that why you are getting errors.